# Chrome devtools exported coverage JSON has all CSS and not only used

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

So I am currently trying to find a way to export only used CSS for my site.

After some reseach I found the chrome devtools coverage feature. It seems to work. It shows that only 1% of my CSS code is used for CSS code from external libraries, e.g. bootstrap and animate.css.

Now there is an export button, which generates a JSON file with the (so I thought) code which I use, but the code in the JSON file is the normal code I use, all 100% not the 1% I use. Whats the point of this feature then?

Now I know that I use only 1% of code, but cannot access it.

Any other ideas how to do it? Or do I not understand the purpose of devtools exported coverage JSON?

[image]

Comment: This JSON should contain `ranges` detected by coverage so you can use an external tool that extracts them, maybe someone wrote it already.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, very helpful. Now I know how I can continue

Comment: You can simply use the json file that the Coverage tool lets you export:

https://nachovz.github.io/devtools-coverage-css-generator/

Comment: This is a similar tool, but with extracting both CSS and JS: https://weisser-dev.github.io/devtools-coverage-extractor/